# How can I load segments of strings from a file into an array?

Tags: regex, perl, file

I have data in a file that I want to load as individual strings. I can format the file any way I want to.
E.g.

```
multilne string  
++++++++++++++  
another multiline string  
++++++++++++++++  
yet another multiline string   
etc
```

How would I read the file and load each string inside these markers (could be anything I can define them as needed) into an array easily and cleanly?

**UPDATE**
May be I was not clear.
I have a series of texts that I need to load in perl. These texts (which are multiline strings essentially nothing really special ascii chars very simple thing) I am planning to just copy/paste them to a file (from various places). What I want is to somehow store them/format them in the file so that I can easily load each string/part into an array.
I mentioned this format as I thought this is a simple format to use. If you have a better solution for this please tell me about it

Comment: Are you saying that the strings are delimited by lines containing multiple plus `+` characters?

Comment: @Borodin:Yes exactly

Comment: Do you want to preserve the _new line_ in multiline strings, or do you wan them to be on a single line?

Comment: @DavidW.:Please see updated OP

Comment: @Jim Regarding your update: it's now clear that you asked an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have asked other questions like this, where you describe *how* you're approaching a problem without describing the actual problem or goal in details. This often limits the answers you get to suboptimal solutions. If you describe the problem itself instead of how you're trying to solve it, I think you will find that you get better answers, free of the arbitrary constraints that you put on them by asking in the XY fashion.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:I did not know about this term.Interesting link, thank you

Comment: If there are no blank lines in your multi-line strings, then the canonical solution is to separate them with blank lines and set `$/ = ''`. Then you can just collect them one by one using `<>`

Answer (score 5):

If you can format the file any way to want, then at least make the separators all the same. Then you can use the `$/` variable to simplify your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

$/ = "\n++\n";

chomp(my @lines = <DATA>);

say Dumper \@lines;

__DATA__
multilne string
++
another multiline string
++
yet another multiline string
etc
```

This gives the following output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'multilne string',
          'another multiline string',
          'yet another multiline string
etc
'
        ];
```

If it works for you, you can even use blank lines and use the special behaviour you get by setting `$/` to an empty string.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

$/ = "";

chomp(my @lines = <DATA>);

say Dumper \@lines;

__DATA__
multilne string

another multiline string

yet another multiline string
etc
```

Which outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'multilne string',
          'another multiline string',
          'yet another multiline string
etc'
        ];
```

Note that the second version even removes the extra newline in the last record.

Comment: Of course, you have to be careful to choose a delimiter that will never appear in your data. `++` would be a poor choice if the file was a list of programming languages, for example.

Comment: I don't understand the popularity of this answer, especially as it doesn't answer the question as asked.

Comment: @Borodin How does it not answer the question as asked?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Because it won't work with the example data

Comment: @Borodin I think the OP made it pretty clear that the example data was just that...an example: "I can format the file any way I want to. E.g. [...]"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Ah, I didn't see that the question had completely changed! I'm sorry, I'm using the tablet app and such things aren't obvious.

Answer (score 3):

If the data is of a size to [slurp](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=504656) you can just split on the lines of interest:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = split /^\++\s*\n/m, do { local $/; <DATA> };

use Data::Dump;
dd \@data;

__DATA__
multilne string  
++++++++++++++  
another multiline string  
++++++++++++++++  
yet another multiline string   
etc
```

Output:

```
[
  "multilne string  \n",
  "another multiline string  \n",
  "yet another multiline string   \netc",
]
```

This is similar to [Recipe 6.7](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_08.htm) in the [Perl Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003137).

If you are concerned about slurping the whole file, just access it lazily with a [memory map](http://search.cpan.org/~leont/File-Map-0.62/lib/File/Map.pm):

```
use File::Map 'map_file';

map_file my $map, '/tmp/data.txt', '+<' ;

my @lines = split /^\++\s*\n/m, $map ;

dd @lines;
# same output
```

---

You asked 'If you have a better solution for this please tell me about it.'

Either use a fixed length invariant delimiter so that you can set the record separator to that. Dave Cross has a [great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25689713/298607).

Or, if you are going to use a variable delimiter, you might consider embedding meta data into it.

Consider the file:

```
++ File 1 
multilne string  
++ File 2  
another multiline string  
++++++ File 3  
yet another multiline string   
etc
```

You could then build a hash of the metadata in the delimiters:

```
@_=split /^\++\s*(.*?(?=\s+\n|\z))\n?/m, $map;
shift @_ if ($_[0] eq '');
%h2=@_;
```

Then you know how you labeled each section:

```
{
  "File 1" => "multilne string  \n",
  "File 2" => "another multiline string  \n",
  "File 3" => "yet another multiline string   \netc",
}
```

If you want to reverse the order of the delimiters to:

```
multilne string  
++ File 1 
another multiline string  
++ File 2  
yet another multiline string   
etc
++++++ File 3
```

You can do:

```
while (my ($v, $k)=(shift @_, shift @_)) {
    last unless defined $k;
    $k=~s/\s*$//;
    $h2{$k}=$v;
}
```

Or,

```
while ($map =~/^(.*?)(?=^\++|\z)^\++\s*(.*?(?=\s+\n|\z))\n?/gms) {
    my $k=$2;
    my $v=$1;
    $k=~s/\s*$//;
    $hash{$k}=$v;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to avoid reading the file line by line. And anyway this results in a less-than-clear solution. IMO slurping an entire file is an evil to be avoided, if only because it makes for poor algorithm design. File data is line-oriented for a reason!

Comment: Well 'clear or less-than-clear' is in the eye of the beholder, no? To *me* this is very clear and idiomatic Perl.

Comment: It treats the file as just a bunch of characters and ignores its line-orientation.

Comment: @Borodin: Isn't the result exactly the same as your solution? The OP requested a file separated into chunks based on a line delimiter. Since the delimiter examples he choose where of variable lengths, a regex is the easiest way. The line structure remains intact inside each chunk -- same as yours...

Comment: Yes, the *result* is probably identical, but software should be written so that it *describes* what it is doing, and to me this doesn't say *"separate a file into blocks delimited by lines containing several plus characters"*

Comment: [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) Both the split on regex of the entire file contents or test each line for a regex match and create a new array element between are idiomatic Perlisms. It is whatever works for the user the best, no?

Comment: Yes there are very many ways to do this, but that's not to say that they're all good ways. A good programming solution is one that expresses it's functionality without needing examination and comprehension. IMO this doesn't do that. It is also bad practice to read all of a file into memory unless it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to specify an alternative delimiter to separate the records of your file.

If you wanted paragraphs, then `local $/ = '';` would split on 2 or more newlines.

Or if you're interested in your custom delim, then `local $/ = "\n+++\n";` would split on a newline followed by three plus signs and then another newline.

#### Use YAML instead

Instead of rolling your own solution, I would recommend using [`YAML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod).

The following script loads 3 paragraphs from a data block.  Outputs the to a YAML file.  Reloads them into a new data structure, and then outputs the result.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML qw(DumpFile LoadFile);

# Load Data from __DATA__ block in paragraph mode
my $data = do {
    local $/ = "";
    [ map { chomp; $_ } <DATA> ];
};

# Output paragraphs to YAML file and then load back in
DumpFile('paragraphs.yaml', $data);

my $newdata = LoadFile('paragraphs.yaml');

# View format of YAML loaded data
use Data::Dump;
dd $newdata;

__DATA__
multiline string 1 line 1
multiline string 1 line 2
multiline string 1 line 3

multiline string 2 line 1
multiline string 2 line 2

multiline string 3 line 1
multiline string 3 line 2
multiline string 3 line 3
```

Outputs:

```
[
  "multiline string 1 line 1\nmultiline string 1 line 2\nmultiline string 1 line 3",
  "multiline string 2 line 1\nmultiline string 2 line 2",
  "multiline string 3 line 1\nmultiline string 3 line 2\nmultiline string 3 line 3",
]
```

Because it's YAML, the data is stored in a human readable and editable format inside `paragraph.yaml` demonstrated below.

However, because it's YAML, this format already supports all data structures that you could ever want without having to add more code like you would for a custom format.

```
---
- |-
  multiline string 1 line 1
  multiline string 1 line 2
  multiline string 1 line 3
- |-
  multiline string 2 line 1
  multiline string 2 line 2
- |-
  multiline string 3 line 1
  multiline string 3 line 2
  multiline string 3 line 3
```

Comment: I like this.I did not know about YAML.But this solves the problem on how to keep the data in an outside file neatly for my script to use. What is the neatest/best way to format the original file where I copy/paste my strings is not solved. You just moved it to the part where I load the file to the YAML api. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Using flip-flop operator excluding start and end line with `++++++++++++++`,

```
my $sep = "++++++++++++++";
my @arr;
while (<DATA>) {
  my $range = /\Q$sep/ ... /\Q$sep/;
  push @arr, $_ if $range >1 and $range !~ /E/;
}
print @arr;

__DATA__
multilne string  
++++++++++++++  
another multiline string  
++++++++++++++++  
yet another multiline string   
etc
```

Comment: Flip-flop?What is that? The `\Q`?

Comment: IMO the range operator is a poor choice for this.

Comment: @Jim: It's the ellipsis `...` - otherwise known as the [*range operator*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

Comment: @Jim from the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) : `\Q` _quote (disable) pattern metacharacters till \E_

Comment: @jm666: Can you explain why it works? Could you fix it if it didn't?

Comment: @Borodin yes, the flip-flop maintains its state and when matches changes the state... in short (when - depends, on the dot's count).. but why is poor?

Comment: That's a description of the range operator; it doesn't describe how this program works. What about `push @arr, split if $range >1 and $range !~ /E/`?

Comment: @jm666 Range operator is used primarily in cases like this and you can check what it returns for every line that is in range. https://eval.in/188934

Comment: @jm666 yes, and `...` is used when separators are same strings, `..` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain exactly how your file is formatted, but going from the example it has separator lines consisting entirely of plus `+` signs with optional trailing spaces.

It is a poor choice of format but this will do that for you.

Note that, if you want to specify the path to the input file on the command line, you can simply change `<DATA>` to `<>` and this will work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = ('');

while (<DATA>) {
  if ( /^\++\s*$/ ) {
    push @data, '';
  }
  else {
    $data[-1] .= $_;
  }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@data;


__DATA__
multilne string  
++++++++++++++  
another multiline string  
++++++++++++++++  
yet another multiline string   
etc
```

**output**

```
[
  "multilne string  \n",
  "another multiline string  \n",
  "yet another multiline string   \netc",
]
```

Comment: What formatting would be better for separation of the strings?

Comment: Maybe a blank line? Or, if your data may contain blank lines, it is common to use a separator that *starts* with a character that cannot usually appear as the first character, such as a dot `.` or a semicolon `;` or colon `:`

Comment: @jaypal:Yeah I like that too.I don't know who/why downvoted this answer earlier.I had removed the downvote

Comment: @Jim Yeah, unfortunately SO doesn't require people to leave a comment when they down vote (mainly due to the fact that it can lead to serial down voting in retaliation). Loss is you never know whats really wrong with the solution. I am no `perl` expert but I don't see anything wrong with this solution.

Answer (score -1):

This will do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $sep = "+";
my @arr;
while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        next if /^[$sep]+?/;
        push (@arr, $_);

}
print "@arr\n";
print $arr[0], "\n";

__DATA__
multilne string
++++++++++++++
another multiline string
++++++++++++++++
yet another multiline string
etc
```

Comment: That just ignores all lines beginning with a plus `+`. Each line of the file ends up as a single element of the array.

Comment: yes, that is true...I though that the purpose of the question was precisely to load each line as a single element in the array...

Comment: It is equivalent to `@arr = grep /^[^+]/, <DATA>; chomp @arr;`

Comment: @PedroA The question is "How would I read the file and load **each string inside these markers**...into an array" (emphasis added).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Yes, the question is poorly phrased. But I tried to clarify the meaning in a comment on the question and it was confirmed. If the OP had wanted that then surely he would have asked *"how can I remove lines with all-plus signs from this data"*?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Yes, it was marked as such. My fault. To be honest, I think your emphasis supports this interpretation! `s/each/every/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60711/discussion-between-borodin-and-thissuitisblacknot).

Comment: Sorry, but the question does not seems clear to me yet. It also says "I want to load as **individual** strings".

Comment: @PedroA Strings, not lines, there's a difference. The thing that should tip you off is the example file, which explicitly states `multiline string`. The OP also responded to Borodin's comment seeking clarification several minutes before you posted your answer.